# Copy Selected Text with VBA and the Adpbe PDF Reader Control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vba

I am trying to copy selected text directly out of a PDF viewer I have made with the Adobe PDF Reader Control in Visual Basic 2010.

I can utilize highlight text with a macro in Word using something this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sel As Selection
    Set Sel = Application.Selection
    If Sel.Type <> wdSelectionIP Then
    MsgBox Sel.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

I am having trouble figuring out whether this bit of code can be used to perform actions with the highlighted text with Adobe PDF Reader. If not, does anyone know how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the Adobe PDF viewer supports VBA.

However, I would suggest an indirect approach, using the clipboard.

By sending a control+c key, the content of the selection will be transferred to the clipboard, and the clipboard could be processed using "native" VBA.

Sending a control+c is done by using `SendKeys("^C")`, see [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

And the Clipboard can be manipulated using [This exampe](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/ManipulateClipboard.htm)